# Why isn't this calculation of the energy of a light wave correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, electricity, photoelectric-effect

I'm trying to calculate the energy $J(T)$ that monochromatic light wave with electric field strength $E(T)$ supplies to unit electric charge over period of time $T$:

$J(T)=\int\limits _{t=0}^{T}E(t)dx(t)=\int\limits _{t=0}^{T}E(t)\frac{dx}{dt}dt=\int\limits _{t=0}^{T}\underbrace{(A_{k}\cos(\omega_{k}t+\psi_{k}))}_{E(t)}\frac{dx}{dt}(t)dt=\int\limits _{t=0}^{T}\underbrace{(A_{k}\cos(\omega_{k}t+\psi_{k}))}_{E(t)}\underbrace{(\frac{A_{k}}{\omega_{k}}\sin(\omega_{k}t+\psi_{k}))}_{\frac{dx}{dt}=\int E(t)dt}dt$

According to literature, I should obtain $\cos^2(\omega_kt+\psi_k)$. But instead I get $\cos\cdot \sin$. What is wrong?

Comment: You seem to have missed the photoelectric effect: photons below a certain energy cannot cause photoelectrons to be ejected in the first place. Next, try saving a lot of math by taking the discrete integral over wavelength of the total power (photons/second/unit-wavelength) to determine the number of incident photons per second.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer appears to be correct, bar the lack of any electric charge in your formula.

If the applied force is solely due to a cosinusoidally varying electric field at a given position (you can ignore the magnetic component of the Lorentz force only if the charge moves non-relativistically), then so is the acceleration. Integrating this with respect to time gives you a sinusoidally varying velocity.

As the transferred energy is given by the integral over time of the product of force and velocity, then you get what you have found.

The integral of this over any whole number of cycles is zero. i.e. The time averaged work done on the charge is zero because the force and velocity are $\pi/2$ out of phase.